# Gmaps4Rails infowindow on mouse over

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I want infowindow to appear when mouse is over a marker, here is my code in coffeescript:

```
$(document).on 'map:ready', -> addHoverHandlers()

addHoverHandlers = ->
  # m is Gmap4Rails marker, doc in gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee
  for m in Gmaps.map.markers
    # marker is a Google Maps Marker
    # https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker
    marker = m.serviceObject

    console.log marker.getPosition().toString()
    # Show the infowindow when user mouses-in
    google.maps.event.addListener marker, "mouseover", ->
      console.log marker.getPosition().toString()
      m.infowindow.open marker.map, marker

    # Hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
    google.maps.event.addListener marker, "mouseout", ->
      m.infowindow.close()
```

This code outputs this on load:

```
(39.7317, -104.92099999999999)
(35.2638, -118.91200000000003)
(36.6624, -121.64499999999998)
```

But this on mouse over of each marker(coordinates does not change):

```
(36.6624, -121.64499999999998)
```

To put question in context, here is how I am triggering `map:ready` event in an erb file:

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Gmaps.map.callback = function(){
            console.log('callback');
            $(document).trigger('map:ready');
        }
    </script>
<% end %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem: I don't know why, but when you loop on Gmaps.map.markers and try to bind a mouseover listener function, it will always evaluate the marker variable as the last marker in the loop.

My workaround is: don't use the marker variable in your mouseover function, use `this` instead which is a [Gmaps Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) object, loop on Gmaps.map.markers and find the one that matches.

Here is the modification for your code:

```
$(document).on 'map:ready', -> addHoverHandlers()

addHoverHandlers = ->
  # m is Gmap4Rails marker, doc in gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee
  for m in Gmaps.map.markers
    # marker is a Google Maps Marker
    # https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker
    marker = m.serviceObject

    console.log marker.getPosition().toString()
    # Show the infowindow when user mouses-in
    google.maps.event.addListener marker, "mouseover", ->
      console.log marker.getPosition().toString()
      # Loop on Gmaps.map.markers and find the one using this
      for m2 in Gmaps.map.markers
        if m2.serviceObject == this
          m2.infowindow.open m2.serviceObject.map, m2.serviceObject

    # Hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
    google.maps.event.addListener marker, "mouseout", ->
      m.infowindow.close()
```

I know it's a very inefficient way to implement the mouseover function. At least, it works.

hth